# String index out of range in Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to make this program to count the number of consecutive characters
and I'm getting the error that says:

> "String index out of range."

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Project0 {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        String sentence;
        sentence = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter a sentence:"); /*Asks the user to
                                                                             enter a sentence*/
        int pairs = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i++){     //counts the pairs of consecutive characters
            if ( sentence.charAt(i) == sentence.charAt(i+1)) pairs++;
        }

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "There were " + pairs + " pairs of consecutive characters");
    }//main
}// Project0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last element in your loop is 100% guaranteed to cause a problem. Perhaps only go to the length - 1 in your loop?

Consider the code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i++){
    if ( sentence.charAt(i) == sentence.charAt(i+1)) pairs++;
}

String s = "AABBCC";

first loop, i = 0 : compare s[0] to s[1]
first loop, i = 1 : compare s[1] to s[2]
first loop, i = 2 : compare s[2] to s[3]
first loop, i = 3 : compare s[3] to s[4]
first loop, i = 4 : compare s[4] to s[5]
first loop, i = 5 : compare s[5] to s[6] // WOAH, you can't do that! there is no s[6]!!
```

Answer (score 0):

`sentence.charAt(i+1)` will cause this as `i + 1 > sentence.length()` at the last step of the for-loop

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the upper limit of your `for` loop to not go all the way to the end because the way you look for consecutive characters is "look at the `i`th character, and then look at the next 
one".  Once you get to the end, there *is* no "next one", so just stop at the next to last one.

```
for (int i = 0; i < sentence.length()-1; i++)
```