# Java - String index out of range error

Tags: java

I keep getting an out of range error when I try to collect string input from the user and convert it to a char type. Here is my code:
Edit: My question hasn't been answered. I put a parameter into my charAt statement but it's still not working. When I run it, it tells me that the problem is on line 33. This question question isn't a duplicate of whatever the link I got was. I can't make sense of the supposedly similar question to this one. Can someone just please tell me what's wrong with line 33?

```
//Arthur Fidas
import java.util.Scanner;   //Needed for Scanner class
import java.lang.String;
/**
    This program computes and displays the shipping charges for Fed Ex.
*/

public class FedEx
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        final double ZONE_A = .6, ZONE_B = 1.0, ZONE_C = 1.25, ZONE_D = 1.4;
        String input;
        char zone;
        String name;
        double weight;
        double total = 0.0;
        int serviceCode;
        int hazardCode;
        double hazardCodeCalculation;

        //Create a Scanner object for keyboard input
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);

        //Prompt user for package weight
        System.out.println("What is the weight of the package?: ");
        weight = keyboard.nextDouble();

        //Prompt user for Zone
        System.out.print("Enter the zone letter: ");
        input = keyboard.nextLine();
        zone = input.charAt(0);

        //Calculate zone price
        switch(zone)
        {
            case 'a':
            case 'A':
                total = weight*ZONE_A;
                break;
            case 'b':
            case 'B':
                total = weight*ZONE_B;
                break;
            case 'c':
            case 'C':
                total = weight*ZONE_C;
                break;
            case 'd':
            case 'D':
                total = weight*ZONE_D;
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Please enter A, B, C, or D.");
                break;
        }

        //Prompt user for service charge
        System.out.println("Enter the Special Service number: ");
        serviceCode = keyboard.nextInt();

        //Caculate Service Charge
        if (serviceCode == 1)
        {
            total += 0;
        }
        else if (serviceCode == 2)
        {
            total += 10;
        }
        else if (serviceCode == 3)
        {
            total += 25;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter 1, 2, or 3.");
        }
        //Prompt user for Hazard Code
        System.out.println("Enter the Hazard Code number :");
        hazardCode = keyboard.nextInt();

        //Calculate Hazard Charge
        switch(hazardCode)
        {
            case 1:
                total += 0;
                break;
            case 2:
                hazardCodeCalculation = total * .1;
                total += hazardCodeCalculation;
                break;
            case 3:
                hazardCodeCalculation = total * .25;
                total += hazardCodeCalculation;
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Please enter either 1, 2, or 3.");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Also it would be helpful if you could help me write code that would display the calculations at the end in the way presented in the comment below:

Comment: and what is the error stacktrace where you are getting `out of range error`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [String index out of range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5011866/string-index-out-of-range)

Comment: The error is coming from the part of the code where i ask for the zone letter and use the input variable for the user's input. and then try to convert the input variable into char using the zone variable

Comment: You're calling `String#charAt` without a parameter, I don't think some of this would even compile. Also for reading inputs, its best to either `String#equalsIgnoreCase` or, in the case of you using `switch`, to switch on something like `Character#toLowerCase` of the input.

Comment: A string isn't a char, as much as it is many chars (an array of them, to be specific). Either pass a parameter to `#charAt` or use the appropriate scanner method for reading a singular character.

Comment: i entered 0 as the parameter for the charAt statement but its still not working i tried everything from -100 to 100

Comment: Your String doesn't get anything in input.Refer my answer for more Information and change that portion of code with corrected code given in answer . I have tried it and Its running smoothly. @ArttyFidasJr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I found some problems in this code part.

```
 //Prompt user for Zone
        System.out.print("Enter the zone letter: ");
        input = keyboard.nextLine();
        zone = input.charAt();
```

First you are taking String input using `.nextLine()` method which may create problem. For more Information about this, Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo).

Another problem is that you are not allocating any character to zone rather you should pass `index` of desiring character in `.charAt()` method.

So you can do this in `two` ways in case you want first character of entered `String`.For another character, change index value in `.charAt()` method.

*1)*

```
//Prompt user for Zone
    System.out.print("Enter the zone letter: ");
    keyboard.nextLine();  //Storing that Enter key Input (Garbage value)
    input = keyboard.nextLine();
    zone = input.charAt(0);
```

*2)*

```
//Prompt user for Zone
    System.out.print("Enter the zone letter: ");
    input = keyboard.next();  //In case your String input doesn't contain Space in between.
    zone = input.charAt(0);
```

If you want to take only `one character` as an `input`, You can take `character` input instead of `String`.

```
//Prompt user for Zone
    System.out.print("Enter the zone letter: ");
    zone = keyboard.next().charAt(0);
```

*Corrected Code*

```
//Arthur Fidas
import java.util.Scanner;   //Needed for Scanner class
import java.lang.String;
/**
    This program computes and displays the shipping charges for Fed Ex.
*/

public class FedEx
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        final double ZONE_A = .6, ZONE_B = 1.0, ZONE_C = 1.25, ZONE_D = 1.4;
        String input;
        char zone;
        String name;
        double weight;
        double total = 0.0;
        int serviceCode;
        int hazardCode;
        double hazardCodeCalculation;

        //Create a Scanner object for keyboard input
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);

        //Prompt user for package weight
        System.out.println("What is the weight of the package?: ");
        weight = keyboard.nextDouble();

        /*THIS FOLLOWING PORTION CAN BE CHANGED WITH PROVIDED SOLUTIONS, TRY ANY OF THEM*/

        //Prompt user for Zone                             
        System.out.print("Enter the zone letter: ");
        input = keyboard.next();
        zone = input.charAt(0);

        /*TILL THIS*/

        //Calculate zone price
        switch(zone)
        {
            case 'a':
            case 'A':
                total = weight*ZONE_A;
                break;
            case 'b':
            case 'B':
                total = weight*ZONE_B;
                break;
            case 'c':
            case 'C':
                total = weight*ZONE_C;
                break;
            case 'd':
            case 'D':
                total = weight*ZONE_D;
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Please enter A, B, C, or D.");
                break;
        }

        //Prompt user for service charge
        System.out.println("Enter the Special Service number: ");
        serviceCode = keyboard.nextInt();

        //Caculate Service Charge
        if (serviceCode == 1)
        {
            total += 0;
        }
        else if (serviceCode == 2)
        {
            total += 10;
        }
        else if (serviceCode == 3)
        {
            total += 25;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter 1, 2, or 3.");
        }
        //Prompt user for Hazard Code
        System.out.println("Enter the Hazard Code number :");
        hazardCode = keyboard.nextInt();

        //Calculate Hazard Charge
        switch(hazardCode)
        {
            case 1:
                total += 0;
                break;
            case 2:
                hazardCodeCalculation = total * .1;
                total += hazardCodeCalculation;
                break;
            case 3:
                hazardCodeCalculation = total * .25;
                total += hazardCodeCalculation;
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Please enter either 1, 2, or 3.");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @ArttyFidasJr.you should accept the answer if it helped you.